# Html2PDF blurry PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, html2pdf

I'm trying to export an HTML page into PDF by using html2pdf.
When I define in the options: "html2canvas:  { **scale: 1** }", I get blurry file.
When I define in the options: "html2canvas:  { **scale: 4** }", At some point of the file, It cuts the inputs text for the rest of the file (as in the picture).
This is my code:

```
var options = {
   margin: 0.1,
   filename: 'Performance Appraisal '+year+'.pdf',
   pagebreak: { after: ['#emp_1_1_2'],
                before: ['#h3_1','#h3_3']},
   html2canvas:  { scale: 4 },
   jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
};
html2pdf().set(options).from(element).toPdf().save();
```

[image: PDF cuts the text of the input]

How can I improve the quality of the PDF file?

Comment: Are the rest of the comments moved to the next page?

Comment: @JM-AGMS No, they just disappeared from that part and throughout the rest of the document.

Comment: I would highly recommend a server-side solution with Puppeteer - all client-side solutions  suffer from glitches here and there, enough to irritate you and your customers.